# Delete multiple files from the NSDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created an application for iOS that works like a document viewer where in I can view documents and it works like charm . I list the files in a table view and have given the swipe feature to delete the files and single file gets deleted . I have enabled the multiple selection during editing as well . The table view rows get selected , but I am not sure how to delete the selected files from the NSDirectory. Can anyone help ?

I have this in didSelectRowForIndexPath :

```
  if (self.tableView.isEditing)
{
    [_selectedRows arrayByAddingObject:[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]]; 
}
```

Ans this when delete button is pressed ,

```
- (void)deleteButton:(id)sender
{
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    for (id object in _selectedRows) {
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:object];

        NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Inbox/"];

        NSString *allFilesPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSString *theactualFilePath = [allFilesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:cellText];    

        NSError *error;

        _success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:theactualFilePath error:&error];
    }

 }
```

This is how i Populate the table view cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"paths :%@",paths);
textlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0, 250, 70)];



NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Inbox/"];

NSString *allFilesPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];



if([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"searchON"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {

    NSString *theFileName = [[_filePathsArrayCopy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] ;

    textlabel.text = theFileName;
}
    else {

  NSString *theFileName = [[_filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] ;



    textlabel.text = theFileName;
}
[cell.contentView addSubview:textlabel];


return cell;
```

}

Comment: ... can't you just abstract the method you use to delete a single file, pull all the selected files into an NSArray, and loop through that calling the delete method ???

Comment: I tried that , And unfortunately all files get deleted . I will post the code .

Comment: please do, seems like a simple mistake

Comment: I have edited the question @jesses.co.tt

Comment: what type is _selectedRows ? where is it being instantiated and set ? where is it being cleared ?

Comment: _selectedRows is a NSArray and I have declared at the top of the class and I have neither set it to any initial values nor cleared it after any operation . Should I do that ?

Comment: I believe you should clear it after you iterate through it on a delete (outside of the for loop, of course.

Comment: I also think that the main problem here is the assignment in your didSelectRowForIndexPath method - you need to add the object to the Array, not assign it to be the whole array...

Comment: Okay , Let me check that and by clearing the array , u mean making it empty again ?

Comment: I am sorry @Droppy but I am not able to understand how is that relevant to what have I asked for ?

Comment: Where am I using NSDictionary @Droppy ?I am loading the table view with the path of the file ?

Comment: just use the sleectedIndexPaths in the delete function. when you tap the delte bitton you do [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]. So you dont need to store it in a class property. Actually i dont know the problem. What is not working?

Comment: @Droppy , get ur reading glasses on . It's NSDirectory .. :@

Comment: @BjörnRo , Let me try that as well ..

Comment: Hahah!  Ooops - I have misread that!  I have never seen the term `NSDirectory` used and assumed it said `NSDictionary`.  Appologies.

Comment: @Droppy , I think ur punishment would be to upvote the question :P

Comment: the strings for your path in the documents folder never change, only the file name. So you should declare the path to the files outside of the the loop. in the loop you only add the cellText for the finalPath ;)

Comment: No.  You are using the tableview as a model store and I cannot encourage that!

Comment: @Droppy nice one :D

Comment: OH yes @BjörnRo , that is very much possible ,  let me do it

Comment: OK, I'll make-up for my earlier mistake by providing a possible solution.  Remove the `didSelectRowForIndexPath` method (and the `_selectedRows` variable)  and use `NSArray *rows = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];` in the `deleteButton` method.  Then iterate through model array using the `row` property of each index path and also delete the entries from the model array outside of the loop.

Comment: oh and dont forget to reload the tableView when your done :)

Comment: I identified the mistake ,the array for selected rows have the indexpaths.. but the selectedcell.textlabel.text is returning null always because of which the whole folder is getting deleted , But why is that happening ?

Comment: @BjörnRo , did you go through my latest comment ? the fault is not with the NSArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So because the comments are to much on the Post i just post a possible Solution.

```
- (void)deleteButton:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    NSString *docPath= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *inboxPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"/Inbox/"];

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        NSString *fileName = [[_filePathsArrayCopy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] ;
        NSString *fullFilePath= [inboxPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName ];

        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullFilePatherror:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: NO , I have found that I am adding a custom UILAbel to the Content View of the cell and that is why the textLAbel.text returns null .. Any way to get the text from that UILAbel ?

Comment: try not to get the tableViewCells like i mentioned in the code, try getting your variables sfrom the list that you used to fill the dataSource

Comment: I didn't understand that .. can you be little more clear ?

Comment: can you tell me how you fill your tableView data? Maybe than i can explain it better. So how do you know how much items the tableView has, how do you set the title of the cells.

Comment: thanks, so your list for filleng the cells is `_filePathsArray` try to use the same one in the delete func